# Is there any way to call PCL method from Android?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I want to navigate from one page to another on info-window click and i have a custom renderer for map. Could anyone suggest me how to navigate to other view from custom renderer. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

You really want to keep the Android project and PCL decoupled, so I would use a [MessagingService](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/xamarin.forms-toolkit/wiki/Services#messagingservice) to send a message from the Android project which will then be received by the PCL.

**YourCustomRenderer:**

```
MessagingService.Current.SendMessage("NavigateMessage", new NavigationParamsModel
{
    TargetPage = "DetailsPage",
    Id = 12,
    SomethingElse = "blahblah"
});
```

**PCL:**

```
MessagingService.Current.Subscribe<NavigationParamsModel>("NavigateMessage", async (arg1, arg2) => 
{
    // Just an example of how this would be done using Prism.Navigation. 
    // Pure Xamarin.Forms navigation is obviously different.
    _navigationService.NavigateAsync(arg2.TargetPage);
});
```